# Как сделать доступным родной клиент в хроме (Native Client)?

Tags: google-chrome, native-client

Как сделать доступным родной клиент в хроме (Native Client)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого необходимо запускать браузер с флагом

```
--enable-nacl
```

Я изменяю параметры запуска у ярлыка браузера. Выберем ярлык хрома, нажимаем правую клавишу мыши и выберем пункт "свойства". Добавляем флаг после имени.